# How do you emit to a room using Socket IO over UDP/Dgram?

Tags: node.js, udp, socket.io

Emitting to rooms is pretty straight forward. How do you emit to a room using Socket IO over UDP/Dgram? Or is this not possible currently. **Not talking about browser usage. Server Only.**

**Socket IO Room Emitting**
https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms

**NodeJS Dgram UDP Example**
http://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html

Can they work together? Or is there a workaround?

Comment: Socket.io currently only lives on tcp, it is possible to build something simular for UDP, but it would be a lot of work, and I can find very little reason this would be useful.  If you would like to communicate server-server with socket.io, the socket.io-client will work for server-server based communication

Answer (score 1):

Um, I'm pretty sure socket.io is TCP-based which means you cannot send UDP datagrams and expect them to be received by a socket.io server.

From [The WebSocket Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455):

> The WebSocket Protocol enables two-way communication between a client running untrusted code in a controlled environment to a remote host that has opted-in to communications from that code.  The security model used for this is the origin-based security model commonly used by web browsers.  The protocol consists of an opening handshake followed by basic message framing, layered over TCP.